# Rails and ajax global error handling issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, error-handling, pjax

I have the following global ajax error handler:

```
App.Utils.AjaxGlobalErrorHandler = {

  isUnauthenticatedStatus: function (request) {
    var status = request.status
    return status == 403;
  },

  displayError: function() {
    $('#ajax-error-modal-window').modal('show');
    $('#ajax-error-message').append("An error occurred. Please, try again.");
  },

  errorMsgCleanup: function() {
    $('#ajax-error-modal-window').on('hidden', function() {
      $('#ajax-error-message').empty();
    });
  },

  handleUnauthorized: function() {
    if ($('#signin').length == 0) {
      window.location = '/signin';
    }
    else {
      $('#signin').trigger('click');
    }
  },

  bindEvents: function() {
    $(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
      if (App.Utils.AjaxGlobalErrorHandler.isUnauthenticatedStatus(xhr)) {
        App.Utils.AjaxGlobalErrorHandler.handleUnauthorized();
      }
      else {
        App.Utils.AjaxGlobalErrorHandler.displayError();
        App.Utils.AjaxGlobalErrorHandler.errorMsgCleanup();
      }
    });
  }

};
```

And then your standard Rails global exception handling:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from Exception, :with => :handle_exceptions

  protected

  def handle_exceptions(e)
    case e
    when AbstractController::ActionNotFound, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, ActionController::RoutingError
      not_found
    else
      internal_error(e)
    end
  end

  def not_found
    render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :layout => false, :status => 404
  end

  def internal_error(exception)
    if Rails.env == 'production'
      ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.exception_notification(request.env, exception).deliver
      render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/500.html", :layout => false, :status => 500
    else
      throw exception
    end
  end

end
```

As you can see, my ajax error handling displays a dialog box.  The issue that I'm having is that when I test the error handling by raising, let's say, an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception in a controller action that returns an html response, the ajaxError event is triggered right before Rails renders the 404 page, the dialog box is shown and then disappears once the 404 page is rendered.  I did not expect the ajaxError event to be triggered in this case.  Can someone explain why? And how can I avoid the ajaxError being triggered when the exception should by handled server-side?  **I am using pjax**, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

This is because jQuery handles an 404 as an error: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L613

In the example you're giving the server catches the ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception in the application controller and returns the result of #not_found. In response of this jQuery detects the 404 and raises the ajaxError event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great. That explains the issue, for sure.  To the second part of my question, how would handle avoiding this issue?

Comment: Could you explain why this is an issue for you, what would you want the server/client to do precisely?